# Error: Too many re-renders issue error, on deployed server env but works fine in local env

Tags: reactjs

In my react js project once I build `npm run build` and deploy it on the server let's say `dev` environment using Webpack. The rest of the project works fine but when I click one specific button in my UI in the dev environment. I get the following error -

`Error: Minified React error #301; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=301 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors`

`Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

But when I try to replicate the issue in my local environment it works completely fine, without any issues. I am not able to find the root cause of this issue.

Please help

Comment: can you add the code for that button and the onclick function that you are calling?

Comment: What do your specific button do? Also send so code as suggest by @Akshay.